# JSRender is not showing the value of JSON object

Tags: jsrender

I'm having issues rendering an AJAX response into a JSRender template.

I'm making a $.getJSON call and on success I call the render(data) function
I'm using the console.log to make sure that the data received from the $.getJSON call is correct.

```
function createNewsPage(event){
                console.log("inside createNewsPage. Event Target: "+ $(event.target).text());
                $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=xyzhere"L,
                          {
                          cache: "true",
                          dataType: "json"
                          },
                          function(data) {insertContent(data);}
                          );
                event.stopPropagation();
                event.preventDefault();
                $("#listviewNews").collapsibleset('refresh');
                return false;
            }

            function insertContent(resp){
                console.log("---data received:\n" + JSON.stringify(resp));
                $("#insertedContent").html(
                                           $("#newsTemplate").render(resp)
                                           ).trigger('create');

            }
```

I don't get any erros, but when the template is rendered it shows the word [object] instead of the actual text content of the JSON payload.

Any idea on why this is happening or how to show the text (string) of the json object as opposed to just saying [object]?

Here is stringfied response (normal RSS feed):

```
{
 "query": {
  "count": 3,
  "created": "2013-03-29T16:12:49Z"
   },
  "results": {
   "item": [
    {
     "title": "BracketRacket: A quiz, a thought and Peeps"
    },
    {
     "title": "Correction: Mandatory Gun Ownership story"
    },
    {
     "title": "Clashes erupt in 2 cities in northern Egypt"
    }
   ]
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Notice that data sent to jsrenderer has to be array, not a JSON object. Can you provide stringified response?

Comment: provided stringified response in the question

Comment: Well no, it can be an object. But what it renders will depend on what your #newsTemplate looks like. In the template, if 'expression' returns an object, 'someObject, {{:expression}} will not stringify the object, it will in effect render someObject.toString().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how your template looks like, but here is example how I would create one:

```
<script id="tmpl" type="text/html">
    <tr>
      <td>{{>title}}</td>
    </tr>  
</script>
```

And I wouldn't pass whole data object, but items instead:

```
$("#insertedContent").html($("#newsTemplate").render(data.results.item))
```

Here is working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gecew/3/

If you need other fields, like count, than have a look on this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gecew/4/

Template will need to look like something this:

```
<script id="tmpl" type="text/html">
    <span>Number of items: <strong>{{>query.count}}</strong></span>
    <ul>
      {{for results.item}}
      <li>{{>title}}</li>
      {{/for}}
    </ul>  
</script>
```

And in this case pass whole data object to render method:

```
$("#insertedContent").html($("#newsTemplate").render(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a console.dir() on the data to see what you're getting there.

You might have to change

```
function(data) {insertContent(data);}
```

to

```
function(data) {insertContent(data.d);}
```